# DJI Windows SDK: What is the API procedure of saving the recorded video of Mavic 2 Pro on the SD card

Tags: dji-sdk

I'd like to know what API from their reference manual to use when I would like to save the recorded video on the SD card with Mavic 2 Pro. I believe that one cannot save video directly on the computer without perhaps using DJI Assistant 2 or so? In their manual (51169 p. 32) for the drone it says that regarding the flight recorder "other parameters" will be automatically saved to the drone's internal data recorder. This internal data recorder, is it referred to its micro SD card? If so, will all default recordings be automatically saved to that SD card? And if still so, is there a way to retrieve these video files via the computer in the code or only through DJI Assistant 2?

My intention is to do something with this video via the computer at the same time running the software I am working on developing (application) in Visual Studio, not to use several different applications. In normal use case scenario as described above, by, I believe, default procedure, would be to record the video, and have it accessed through the Assistant 2 app, and copy that video file over to the application I am working on, and from there present some options to the user with the video, like replay it faster.